# How can I change the ComboBox trigger to show a search icon?

Tags: extjs3

The [ComboBox component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox) shows a dropdown icon for the trigger. How can I show a search icon instead? I am using ExtJS 3.X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `triggerClass` config. I found a class `x-form-search-trigger` that seems to work. Here is a simple example:

```js
new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Color',
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        displayField: 'text',
        valueField: 'value',
        triggerClass: 'x-form-search-trigger',
        store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            data: [
                { text: 'Green', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Blue', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Red', value: '3' },
            ],
            fields: [ 'text', 'value' ]
        })
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```